# OCSP and CrlClient takes aroung 1hour to complete revocation checking

Tags: itext, ocsp, certificate-revocation

I am trying to check for revocation of my certificate. I have CAcert certificate.
It takes around 1hour for crlClient and also for OCSP to complete revocation checking of certificate.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How long does it take to download the CRL when using the Java API?

Comment: The CRLs by CACert are monstruous because (1.) they don't clean up expired certificates, (2.) they don't create sufficient intermediary certificates, (3.) the certificates are free which makes the threshold to revoke a certificate low. The real question would be: *Hey CACert, can you do something about your huge CRLs?*

Comment: It helps to use a local cache of the CRL. We had a similar issue in the iText tests, we also had to use CRL caching.

Comment: It takes around 1hour to download crl file. It's a 7MB file